# PHP Ajax function not posting data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use Jquery to call an ajax function, which updates an MySQL database. I have several other Ajax requests in the same file and they work fine. For some reason the getinvoices value is not being passed to the PHP file. I'm calling the function on click of a button, below is the code I'm using.

#### Javascript

```
$( "#updatexero" ).button().on( "click", function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'invoices.php',
        data: { getinvoices: 1 },
        success: function(){
            $( "#sql-confirm" ).dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    OK: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

#### PHP - invoices.php

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['getinvoices'])) {
    //Code to do stuff
}
```

If I do `echo $_POST['getinvoices'];`, it says undefined index, as no value has been passed. I can't see why this shouldn't work, what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I have solved the issue now, the problem was another `if` statement in `invoices.php` that wasn't getting called, so nothing to do with the Ajax query. The firebug extension proved handy for debugging though.

Comment: check request in network from developer Tools, this codes must work!

Comment: It is calling the php file but not sending the value of getinvoices, i have almost the exact same code elsewhere in the same file and it works

Comment: This code should work. I've tried it and it correctly posts the `getinvoices=1`. Have you tried a `get` instead of a `post`? It's a little easier to debug a get request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correctly written.
I adopted your code "as is" and put it on my own server.

In `invoices.php` I simply put:

```
<?php 
    print_r( $_POST );
?>
```

This is the result I got when checking in the debug console:

[image]

I would advise you to use this debug console to check your AJAX request. It's included in both Chrome and FireFox. In chrome you need to install the extension Firebug Lite however. 
You'll see in my picture that `getinvoices` is both included in the AJAX post and received by the `invoices.php` script.

The debug console will also alert you if there is a syntax error in your JavaScript code.

However.. you can change the following code:

```
$( "#updatexero" ).button().on( "click", function(event) {
```

to

```
$("#updatexero").click(function(event){
```

Comment: You're right, I tried `invoices.php` with just a simple sql query and it worked, it must be something else in `invoices.php` that is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

 $( "#updatexero" ).on( "click", function(event) {
                $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url: 'invoices.php',
                data: { getinvoices: 1 },
                success: function(){
                      $( "#sql-confirm" ).dialog({
                      modal: true,
                      buttons: {
                        OK: function() {
                          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                      }
                    });

                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your code .

Remove `.button()` as it does not match the syntax here.

Try below code :-

```
$("#updatexero").on("click", function(event) {
         //// Your code.
    });
```

For more information check out below link :-

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: If the `button()` returns the jQuery object - what it normally does - this is valid method chaining.

Comment: can you link to some documentation for this @DerVO?

Comment: I have removed `.button()` but it still doesn't work, I don't think its the problem as I have used it elsewhere in my code without any problems

Comment: @Neel I assume this is the button widget from jQuery UI - this returns the jQuery object containing the button element (http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-widget). Here is a demo for this syntax : http://jsfiddle.net/tolund/S8D6n/